# Copying cell matrix values to new matrix MATLAB

Tags: matlab, csv, matrix, cell

I have 60 values in a cell matrix from a .csv file which are stored in column 15 from rows 38556-38616

I want to copy that range of values to a regular numerical 60x1 matrix in a variable `Value`

Here is what I tried:

```
Values(60,1) = data2{38556:38616,15};
```

It only copies 1 value from data2 and the rest of values from rows 1-59 are 0. How can I copy
those values to `Value` in the same order they are in the file? `data2` is the cell matrix storing .csv file values.

Image of `data2`:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either

```
Values(1:61,1) = cell2mat(data2(38556:38616,15));
```

or just

```
Values = [data2{38556:38616,15}]';
```

The problem was that you tried to store 61 values into just one matrix element.

Comment: You first line only returns 60 instances of the same value. Second line works but i'd like it as a 60,1 matrix. Second line returns a 1x61

Comment: @loco: Then transpose it with `'`.  The reason you have 61 values is that you actually specified 61 rows.

Comment: Used reshape before you posted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Incidentally, if you don't need the full contents of the csv file, just a subset, and the contents you are reading in are numeric, you can take this directly from the file using `dlmread`.  For example:

`values = dlmread('data.csv',',',[38555 14 38615 14]);`

The numeric values are starting and ending positions: `[R1 C1 R2 C2]`.  `dlmread` starts counting at zero for R/C values.  You can also use spreadsheet style instead, i.e. `'A4..G6'` or in your case I think it would be `'O38556..O38616'`.